# Sum dynamic range in pivot table but certain row(s)

Tags: excel, pivot-table, offset

I'm not quite at the level of using VBA or an issue like this, though I'm open to trying, but I am looking for a formula (or other method) that will allow me to sum the values in a dynamic range while excluding certain rows.

I have many pivot tables set up in the following fashion:

```
2013
    Oct      10
    Nov      20
    Dec      10
2014         40
    Jan      20
    Feb      30
    Mar      20
Grand Total  110
```

I have been trying to create a formula that sums the last 6 months, but excludes the subtotal (as seen next to `2014`), so I only sum Mar-2014, Feb-2014, Jan-2014, Dec-2013, Nov-2013, Oct-2013. When we add to the source data, we will see Apr-2014, May-2014, etc, so I am trying to create a dynamic range that only counts the last six months. So far, I have used:

```
=OFFSET($Grand Total$110, -7, 0, 6, 0)
```

to try to capture the six rows leading up to the grand total row. I have tried to create an if function that says:

"if(OFFSET($Grand Total$110, -7, 0, 6, 0)=[cell with subtotal for 2014],sum(OFFSET($Grand Total$110, -7, 0, 6, 0))-[cell with subtotal for 2014],sum(OFFSET($Grand Total$110, -7, 0, 6, 0))"

but the offset function doesn't appear to act as a "range."

Is there a way to sum an offset function but exclude the subtotal row from the calculation? The problem with doing:

sum(OFFSET($Grand Total$110, -7, 0, 6, 0))-[row with subtotals]

is that once you get to Jun-2014, you will be subtracting the subtotal even though it isn't in the last 6-month range, e.g.,

```
2014   [Subtotal]
   Jan (6 months ago)
   Feb (5 months ago)
   Mar (4 months ago)
   Apr (3 months ago)
   May (2 months ago)
   June (last month)
```

I hope my issue makes sense and that someone might have a useful, formula-driven solution for this.

Comment: You could turn off subtotals (and grand totals) in the pivot tables. That might make life a little easier, but you're still dealing with the PT format, which is rather fragile. I'd suggest pointing some `SUMIFS` at the source of the pivot, where you can obtain a rolling 6-month (or most recent 6-month) total pretty easily. The exact method depends on how your data is structured though.

Comment: @andyholaday has a good suggestion. I always prefer adding calculated columns to a pivot table's source data if possible. You might also be able to use `GETPIVOTDATA` formulas, which can be dynamic: See this [Contextures page](www.contextures.com/xlPivot06.html)